# Writing a PDF to filesystem iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, pdf, quartz-graphics

I am am opening a PDF document using Quartz2D in core graphics, resizing it, and attempting to re-save it to the file system of an iPhone.  Problem is I cannot figure out how to write a PDF to the file system.  Has anyone had luck with such a problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all Check this [Apple Document](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101)

Then suppose upon a button press you want to save your created pdf file

-(IBAction)save:(id)sender{

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *dirctryForSaving = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *saveFileName = @"One.pdf";

NSString *newFilePath = [dirctryForSaving stringByAppendingPathComponent:saveFileName];

const char *filename = [newFilePath UTF8String];

    //Calling CreatePDFFile()

CreatePDFFile(Your Pdf file size,filename);
```

}

CreatePDFFile(Your Pdf file size,filename){

//Create you pdf file

}

Comment: I should have been more explicit but I basically need to print a PDF file programatically, not just save the file to the device.  I have not found a solution yet, but this project is on the back burner so its less of an issue.  Thanks for your input though.